# How do I remove KEF Spring Ceiling Speakers?

Tags: speakers

I have a set of in-ceiling speakers that need to be removed. After searching online I believe we've identified them as the picture attached. However, when we attempt to pull them down they feel very fixed in place.

How can these be removed? The model is KEF CI3-80QT

[image: Picture of the speakers from behind]

Comment: The peakers' manual is available free online, for instance [here](https://www.manua.ls/kef/ci3-80qt/manual). You'll have to either release the clips that hold the speaker in place (perhaps by accessing the speaker from the crawl space above the ceiling), or cut out the ceiling material around the speaker clips so the speakers can be withdrawn. But I have no experience with these speakers, and the manufacturer or its dealers might have better suggestions or methods.

Comment: Have you tried using a utility knife or other thin-bladed tool to slide around the edge? Maybe there is some paint sticking it to the ceiling.